# Protected generic class - is it supported?

Tags: c#, class, generics, abstract, protected

I had a question on C# generics. I wish to store a generic type variable in my abstract class without declaring that type outside the class.

Below is the code sample. Please note that I do not wish to make the **Param** classes exposed outside the **Calc** class.

Thanks in advance.
- Dutta.

```
abstract class Base { }

abstract class Calc<T> where T : Base
{
    protected Param Member; /* how can this be a made a generic declaration 
                             * WITHOUT declaring this class like,
                             * class Calc<T, P> 
                             *      where T : Base
                             *      where P : Param */

    protected Calc(Param p)
    {
        this.Member = p;
    }

    protected abstract class Param { }
}

class MyBase : Base { }

class MyCalc : Calc<MyBase>
{
    public MyCalc() : base(new MyParam()) { }

    public void doSomething()
    {
        base.Member.A++; // fails on compilation
    }

    private class MyParam : Calc<MyBase>.Param
    {
        public int A;

        public MyParam() { this.A = 0; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want a protected class? What are you trying to accomplish/prevent? What isn't working? What you have looks ok

Comment: I need a protected **Param** class as I want only classes derived from **Calc** to be able to instantiate and invoke methods on it.

Comment: That's a different requirement than saying that you don't want the `Param` generic type parameter to be "public".

Comment: Ya, I don't want it to be public.

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so, please mark it as such. If not, please let us know why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to cast it to the new type, because no matter what, the variable Member was declared as Param and it will always be accessed as Param:

```
((MyParam)base.Member).A++;
```

Secondly, you can fix up your MyParam class by changing from this:

```
MyParam : Calc<MyBase>.Param
```

To this:

```
MyParam : Param
```

Because Param is already `Calc<MyBase>` through generics and inheritance.

Comment: Quite right- I wrote it in that fashion so make the code explicit. I do not have a compilation error on that line.

Comment: I didn't notice you pointed out where you were having the error. I've updated the answer to reflect what I think you need to do.

Comment: Thraka's updated answer is correct. The cast is necessary as long as you're not using generics. No matter what, the types used for generic type parameters have to have the same visibility as the generic class itself - and in your case, the same visibility as how the parameter is exposed from the class.

Comment: Although casting is something I would like to avoid as far as possible, but I cannot deny that this is indeed a way ahead. Thanks to both Thraka and Lars for having attempted to answer this. I have marked this as a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thraka's answer is correct: if you don't want to use generics you need to cast. Just to add to it, in case what you're really trying to do looks something like this. Here's a set of classes that you can expose from your library, which will not be extensible by clients (unless they're running with full trust and can use reflection etc.!!) but which can be used in a type-safe way.

```
public abstract class SupportedPaymentMethod
{
    protected internal SupportedPaymentMethod() { }
}

public sealed class Check : SupportedPaymentMethod
{
    public int CheckNumber { get; private set; }

    public Check(int checkNumber)
     : base()
    {
        CheckNumber = checkNumber;
    }
}

public sealed class CreditCard : SupportedPaymentMethod
{
    public CreditCard()
     : base()
    { }
}

public abstract class Payment<T>
    where T : SupportedPaymentMethod
{
    public T Method { get; private set; }

    protected internal Payment(T method)
    {
        Method = method;
    }
}

public sealed CheckPayment : Payment<Check>
{
    public CheckPayment(Check check)
     : base(check)
    { }
}

public sealed CreditCardPayment : Payment<CreditCard>
{
    public CreditCardPayment(CreditCard creditCard)
     : base(creditCard)
    { }
}
```

Clients (i.e. code outside of your class library's assembly) will be able to instantiate a `CheckPayment` or a `CreditCardPayment`, but they will not be able to create a new class deriving from `Payment<T>`. So, it will not be possible for clients to create a `CheatingPaymentMethod : Payment<Cheating>`, for example. :)

Calls like your intended call to `base.Member.A++` will now work:

```
var checkPayment = new CheckPayment(new Check(123456));
var checkNumber = checkPayment.Method.CheckNumber; // Success! :)
```